# How to get output of awk into a tab-delimited file merging two lines to a line every time?

Tags: bash, awk

I have multiple files in gz format and used this script which counts lines in each file and prints 1/4 of lines for each file:

```
for file in *.gz;
do echo $file;
gunzip -c $file | wc -l | awk '{print, $1/4}';
done
```

STDOUT:

```
AB.gz
12
CD.gz
4
```

How I can pipe outputs of awk into a tab-delimited file like this merging two lines each time:

```
AB.gz 12
CD.gz 4
```

I tried paste by piping `| paste -sd '\t' > output.txt` in the script but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script like this:

```
for file in *.gz; do
   gzcat "$file" | awk -v fn="$file" -v OFS='\t' 'END{print fn, int(NR/4)}'
done
```

Comment: Thanks. How I can write the stdout to a file within the script? e.g.: > output.txt  not working..

Answer (score 1):

Do not echo a newline after the file:

```
for file in *.gz;
do
   printf "%s " "${file}"
   gunzip -c $file | wc -l | awk '{print, $1/4}';
done
```